# Replay interface calls for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing

My backend library has a simple functional interface. I hoped to have full test coverage, but I have not yet achieved that. As a result, some calls from the web application are causing problems. I would like to store those calls to be able to reproduce the errors in a simple setup (without the webapp). What I am thinking is:

```
@testcase
def func1(*args, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
    return sth
```

And the `testcase` decorator would just store all calls to `func1` somewhere, so that I can reuse that for testing.

I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel here. Is there any library available to perform such a "function call recording"?

Or do you have any other suggestion on how to approach this problem?